# How to download an excel spreadsheet without opening a windows popup window

Tags: java, selenium, headless, google-chrome-headless

There is a spreadsheet to download using java+selenium in headless mode.
The thing is I'm using to execute this test cases a Linux server(CI/CD). The code is working 100% correct, When I'm using my local computer(Windows) to execute this code.

```
ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-infobars");
chromeOptions.addArguments("--browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk",
"application/vnd.ms-excel,
vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet,application/excel");
chromeOptions.addArguments("--test-type");
chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-gpu");
chromeOptions.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
chromeOptions.addArguments("--no-zygote");
chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage");

Map<String, Object> chromePrefs = new HashMap<>();
chromePrefs.put("profile.default_content_settings.popups", 0);
chromePrefs.put("download.prompt_for_download", "false");
chromePrefs.put("cmd", "Page.setDownloadBehavior");

if (OS.startsWith("windows")) {
    chromePrefs.put("download.default_directory", path+WIN_RESOURCES_PATH);
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", ".\\src\\main\\resources\\driver\\chromedriver.exe");

    if (Parameters.instance().getHeadless().toLowerCase().equals("true")) {
        chromeOptions.addArguments("--headless");
        }
        } else if (OS.startsWith("linux")) {
            chromePrefs.put("download.default_directory", path+LIN_RESOURCES_PATH);
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", Parameters.instance().getChromeDriver());
            if (Parameters.instance().getHeadless().toLowerCase().equals("true")) {
                chromeOptions.addArguments("--headless");
            }
        }

chromeOptions.setExperimentalOption("prefs", chromePrefs);
chromeOptions.addArguments("window-size=1920,1080");
driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
driver.get(getUrl());
driver.findElement(locator).click;
driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
```

My code is something like this. When Selenium test clicks the download button, opening another tab in browser and also a popup window, asking where to "Save" the file.

"I'm running these tests in headless chrome"

Comment: So on the CI/CD server, Chrome is asking the user where to save the excel spreadsheet?

Comment: And Chrome is not showing the "File save as..." prompt when running the tests locally?

Comment: I wonder if this has something to do with the HTTP headers sent with the file from the windows server (content-type along with content-disposition). These headers can be used to force a download prompt in the browser, regardless of browser preferences.

Comment: @gregBurghardt Can't check it since the headless mode is on. I will take a screenshot and will let you know. I think yes prompting a File save as window.

Comment: @GregBurghardt No, there is no prompt window opening.

Answer (score 0):

For me the following code works for pdf download  (Windows)
With these option no promot and it will download your predefined path.

```
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "chromedriver.exe");

        Path download_folder = Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.home") + "/Downloads", new String[0]);

        HashMap<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap();
        prefs.put("download.default_directory", download_folder.toAbsolutePath());
        prefs.put("download.prompt_for_download", Boolean.valueOf(false));
        prefs.put("download.directory_upgrade", Boolean.valueOf(true));
        prefs.put("plugins.plugins_disabled", new String[] { "Chrome PDF Viewer" });

        HashMap<String, Object> options = new HashMap();
        options.put("prefs", prefs);

        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
        capabilities.setCapability("chromeOptions", options);
        driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
```